# High resolution images and the retina display

Tags: iphone, ios

Am a newbie to iOS App development and to design. I was wondering about these 2 questions:

can I create a high-resolution image & use it for all the devices (be it retina or non-retina)? (why should one create a low-resolution image intentionally for a non-retina device? why can't everything be simply high-resolution?) ... I hope it isn't a dumb question!

And what do we exactly mean by 'high-resolution' here? '1024pixels X 1024pixels' ? how high is 'high'' really for a retina display?

Any help please?

Comment: To prevent wasting valuable memory, and scaling images which may produce unwanted results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"High Resolution" means twice the pixels in each dimension on iOS (and OSX). So if you have an image that is 23x10 pixels on a non-retina display, the high resolution version of it must be 46x20 pixels in size.

If you name your high resolution images like this: lowResImageName`@2x`.png, the system will automatically choose the high res image on retina devices.

As others have said, you use special low-res images to maximize quality (because you can choose to leave fine details out of a low-res image, etc.) and minimize memory footprint (because the non-retina variants have had half the RAM of the retina versions so far).

It also helps to think in non-retina pixels, because one non-retina pixel equals one "display point", the unit in which iOS measures sizes.

Answer (score 2):

iOS devices' resolution is as follows:

```
                          standard            retina
iPhone, iPod Touch       320 x 480          640 x 960
iPad                     768 x 1024         1536 x 2048
iPhone 5                     -              640 x 1136
```

Why create a low-resolution image? Because it will automagically be used on non-retina devices, saving memory.

Answer (score 1):

For some images that will work just fine, but for certain ones (if your image has some fine text for example), they will come out looking jagged or distorted when scaled down automatically. There may also be cases when you want something displayed differently(I've had occasional images with cool gradient effects that just don't look right on a low res device, so I've had to remove some detail in the low res image to make it look okay).

The other answer is also correct in that if you allow for both cases, low res devices will only load the low res images into memory, so the app will be using less memory. This is only an optimization for those cases, but it is still helpful since typically you can assume that the low res devices will have less memory to begin with since they are older.

Comment: +1 It was a good explanation from design perspective! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Retina graphics, the high resolution graphics you are mentioning, should be double the point values for width and height. What I mean by that is, on all iPhone-sized devices, the size of the screen is 320 points by 480 points. On non-retina devices, translates to 320 pixels by 480 pixels. On retina devices, this translates into 640 pixels by 960 pixels. Everything is double in both the horizontal and vertical directions.

What this means, is you should have two versions of all your image assets. So if you have image that you want on the screen that is 44 points wide by 44 points tall, you should have two images ... Image.png which will be 44 pixels by 44 pixels, and Image@2x.png which will be 88 pixels by 88 pixels (for retina devices, this is what the @2x represents).

Why have two versions, and not just the high rez version? Because it takes processing power to 'compress' the larger version into a smaller version. It's much easier to just already have the lower resolution version, and you are saving valuable memory.

Answer (score 0):

The first question was answered by H2CO3. You safe memory on old devices (think of iPhone 3G, many current Apps are terribly slow, yet well-coded apps still work fine)

What does high-resolution mean?

E.g. on a non-retina device you can show some `example.png` of 300x200 pixels using `[UIImage imageNamed:"example.png"]`.

High-res would mean, you had an additional `example@2x.png` of 600x400 pixels, i.e. double size. Then you're app size is bigger, both devices have appropriate graphics but you save memory on the old device (Which would have to allocate 4 times the memory with no added improvement for the user, because it still has only a 300x200 pixel-display-space for a 600x400 pixel image).