# UIImage resize performance and quality issue

Tags: ios, resize, uiimage

I'm working with UIImage and like everyone else have to deal with retina and non-retina display adaptability. As for as I know, retina display requires double pixels.

I'm wondering if I could simply use a large image with the same width/height ratio, just resize it smaller to adapt all device?

For example, I made a original image with size of 200*200 pixel. Now I want to use it in application as 20*20 pixel, and 80*80 pixel (two situations). Then I have to make four copies like img2020.png, img2020@2x.png, img8080.png and img8080@2x.png

So if I want to use it in three situations with difference size, I have  to store 6 copies. Can I just use UIImage's resize function to do this? I've tried a bit but cannot figure out it's quality and performance.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11266873/1059705 this link might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All native API suppose you to use `image.png` and `image@2x.png`, so it may be difficult sometimes to use just one image and scale it depending on retina/non-retina. Moreover using retina graphics on non-retina devices lead to more extensive use of these devices' resource causing battery drain. And, of course, if you have many images, that will decrease performance of your application. **In other words there are reasons to use double set of images and you should better use it instead of one large image being scaled**.

Comment: Considering both the link from @Bala and this answer, I would like to accept this answer be because I think it's better to make both copies for retina and non-retina.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make 6 copies. You should use the size `200*200 pixel`. And set the property `contentMode` of `imageview` to `aspectFit`. Or you can also use below function and change the size of images at run time.

```
-(UIImage *)Resize_Image:(UIImage *)image requiredHeight:(float)requiredheight andWidth:(float)requiredwidth
{ 
    float actualHeight = image.size.height; 
    float actualWidth = image.size.width; 
    if (actualWidth*requiredheight <actualHeight*requiredwidth) 
    {
        actualWidth=requiredheight*(actualWidth/actualHeight);
        actualHeight=requiredheight; 
    } 
    else
    { 
        actualHeight=requiredwidth*(actualWidth/actualHeight);   actualWidth=requiredwidth;
    }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight); 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size); 
    [image drawInRect:rect]; 
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some comparisons before. Leaving iOS handle the resizing causes lower quality, and really unacceptable sometimes.

I feel lazy sometimes, my approach is to run it with the retina version, and if it looks bad, I will create a low-res version.

If you're writing an iPhone-only app, most of iPhones on the market has retina, so I don't think you should worry about non-retina version. Just my opinion though.